# Extending and/or parametric object as attribute

Tags: class, prolog, swi-prolog, parametric-polymorphism, logtalk

As I understand now from [Array as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886866/objectifying-array-based-on-term/71887537#71887537) I have to use parametric object, because using non-parametric Logtalk objects implies that I have to use assert i.e. any change/set rewrites the whole array.

The problem is then :

- how do you EXTEND the Array class..
- OR instantiate it as ATTRIBUTE in the host class

Point 1

```
:- object(a2d, instantiates(array)).

:- end_object.
```

- ```
  Reference to unknown object: array
  ```

even if it works, how do u access it internally .

Point2

means modifying the Term somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that *parametric object* solution, the object is used to encapsulate the predicates working on the array representation and object parameter is used to hold the (compound) term representing an array itself.

The parametric object, a *prototype* in this case, can be *extended* as any other prototype:

```
:- object(a2d(_Array_), extends(array(_Array_)).

:- end_object.
```

Note that the identifier of the parametric object is `array(_)` (i.e. a compound term). Thus, `array(_)` and `array` are identifiers for different objects.

Comment: Domain error: value array(A) is not in domain class

Comment: Sorry. Copy and paste error. Fixed now.

Comment: bummer ;) .....

Comment: Array ==> _Array_

Comment: Note that you only need to write an object parameter using the syntax `_ParameterName_` when you want to access it as illustrated in the other linked answer (there are other ways to access object parameters). I.e. your `Array` to `_Array_` edit of my answer is only advised iff in the `a2d` object you're adding predicates (or directives) that refer to the parameter.

Comment: yes i do..plus i override get/set